# How to change the width of columns in a table that has merging cells

Tags: tables, multicolumn, width

looking around in forums but I can't find the solution for it.

I have a table as below. How can we change the width of columns 3rd (A, 2, 5) and 4th (B, 3, 4) so that they have same width value?

Thanks,

```
    \begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c}
    \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Type of raw materials}} &   \multirow{2}{*}{Stock} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{
        \begin{tabular}[c]{c} Demande quantity of raw material \\ to manufacture a product \end{tabular}}       &  \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &           & A           & B           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    I                      & 18        & 2           & 3           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    II                     & $30$      & 5           & 4           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.se!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`array`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package   to customize columns, you can for example define new column type for column 3 and 4 rather then `c` try with 
`>{\centering}m{2.5cm}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{\centering}m{2.5cm}|>{\centering}m{2.5cm}|c}
    \cline{1-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Type of raw materials}} &   \multirow{2}{*}{Stock} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{
        \begin{tabular}[c]{c} Demande quantity of raw material \\ to manufacture a product \end{tabular}}       &  \\ \cline{3-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{} &           & A           & B           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    I                      & 18        & 2           & 3           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    II                     & $30$      & 5           & 4           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Or you can define new column type with

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering}m{2.5cm}}
```

Which can be applied for column 3 and 4

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C|C|c}
```

**Result**

[image]